# Error <path> attribute d expected number in mathjax-node

Tags: python, node.js, svg, mathjax

I'm using `mathjax-node` to try to convert mathjax code into an SVG. Currently, the code I have set up here is this:

```
const mathjax = require("mathjax-node");

process.stdin.on("data", data => {
  mathjax.typeset({
    math: data.slice(1),
    format: [...data][0] == "Y" ? "inline-TeX" : "TeX",
    svg: true
  }).then(data => {
    process.stdout.write(data.svg + String.fromCodePoint(0));
  });
});
```

Which takes in input and the first character determines if it's inline or not and everything else is the code. It's used by a python file like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from subprocess import *

from pathlib import Path

cdir = "/".join(str(Path(__file__)).split("/")[:-1])
if cdir:
  cdir += "/"

converter = Popen(["node", cdir + "mathjax-converter.js"], stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE)

def convert_mathjax(mathjax, inline = True):
  converter.stdin.write(bytes(("Y" if inline else "N") + mathjax, "utf-8"))
  converter.stdin.flush()
  result = ""
  while True:
    char = converter.stdout.read(1)
    if not char: return ""
    if ord(char) == 0:
      return result
    result += char.decode("utf-8")
```

So `convert_markdown` is the function that takes the code and turns it into the SVG. However, when I try to render the output just using `data:text/html,<svg>...</svg>`, it gives this error in the console:

```
Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "…3T381 315T301241Q265 210 201 149…".
```

Using MathJax client-side with the `_SVG` config option works fine, so how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that there is an error in that SVG path.  The `T` command is supposed to have two coordinate parameters.  But there is one in the middle there that doesn't.

```
T 381 315 T 301241 Q ...
```

is probably supposed to be:

```
T 381 315 T 301 241 Q ...
```

Either there is a bug in the mathjax SVG generator, or something else in your code is accidentally stripping random characters.